# Specifying my own openGL coordinates

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I have an `NSOpenGLView` with its default coordinates set to an equidistant grid from -1 to +1 in the x direction, and -1 to +1 in the y direction. However, I want to set my opengl view to have its coordinates range from `-width / 2 to +width / 2` in the x direction, and `-height / 2 to +height / 2` in the y direction instead. I tried setting setting the projection using `glOrtho(-w/2, w/2, -h/2, h/2, 0, 1);` but I seem to have no success as my view is blank when I draw a triangle. Can anyone shed some light on my situation?

Comment: You can not change OpenGL coordinates system (NDC). But you can scale and/or translate your own "world" coordinates to NDC. And place the camera so you can see the transformed coords. And ortho/perspective project them. If you don't understand these concepts then you need a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally get it down. Here's an example of my working solution:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)bounds
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-_w / 2., _w / 2., -_h / 2., _h / 2.,  0., 1.);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    // Draw something:
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertexd(-100., -100.);
    glVertexd(-100., 100.);
    glVertexd(100., 100.);
    glVertexd(100, -100.); 
    glEnd();
}
```

Much kudos goes to user1240679: [Setting the coordinate system for drawing in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506949/setting-the-coordinate-system-for-drawing-in-opengl)